# Using serialPort C++ dll in uwp

Tags: c++, windows, dll, uwp, serial-port

I have a C++ dll for serial port communication with an gnss board. The dll uses win32 CreateFile, WriteFile and ReadFile. I already accomplished to import the dll in the Unity UWP. When running in the Unity debug window, the dll functions work, but when I build the app and run it as an app on my Computer, the dll is not able to access the SerialPort.

I know I have to add some capability and tired this one according to windows documentation:

```
<DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
  <Device Id="any">
    <Function Type="name:serialPort" />
  </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

But this is not working here. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: UWP apps run in a sandbox, it disables direct access to devices.  Necessary to ensure that manifest capabilities are observed.  CreateFile is *verboten*.  You must use the SerlalPort class instead.

Comment: Is there no way to use win32 dll's ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to use Win32 dlls indirectly by using brokered component but for that your app needs to be installed in sideloaded mode.

For more information, have a look [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj4hKaq5KHWAhUGp48KHSRHAqoQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fwindows%2Fuwp%2Fwinrt-components%2Fbrokered-windows-runtime-components-for-side-loaded-windows-store-apps&usg=AFQjCNHcLs3DxlyrC854WMxveTrFIh0BVw).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

ReadFile / WriteFile are OK, but CreateFile is not on [the list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-apis).

You can replace CreateFile with [CreateFile2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449422(v=vs.85).aspx).